# Check if date between date range that also handle null values Java

Tags: java, date, date-comparison

My standard method for checking if a date is between two dates in Java looks like this:

```
public static boolean isWithinRange(Date date, Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    return !(date.before(startDate) || date.after(endDate));
}
```

I want to add support for null values on startDate or endDate (meaning user hasn't entered a date. If startDate is null I only want to check endDate and if endDate is null I only want to check startDate and if both null then it is true. My current solution looks like this:

```
public static boolean isWithinRange(Date date, Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    if (startDate == null && endDate == null) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!(startDate != null || !date.after(endDate))) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!(endDate != null || !date.before(startDate))) {
        return true;
    }

    return !(date.before(startDate) || date.after(endDate));
}
```

alternative more readable example:

```
public static boolean isWithinRange(Date date, Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    if (startDate == null && endDate == null) {
        return true;
    }

    if (startDate == null && date.before(endDate))) {
        return true;
    }

    if (endDate == null && date.after(startDate))) {
        return true;
    }

    return date.after(startDate) && date.before(endDate));
}
```

But it feels like really bad code. Is there any other way to deal with this?

Comment: All the !'s are making it rather difficult for me to read. But you might consider whether this would be a better fit for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It's to make it inclusive instead of strictly before and after.

Comment: assylias’ answer is best, but the second version of your code is pretty reasonable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about:

```
return (startDate == null || !date.before(startDate))
    && (endDate == null || !date.after(endDate));
```

---

This uses the fact that these two statements are equivalent:

```
!(date.before(startDate) || date.after(endDate))
!date.before(startDate) && !date.after(endDate)
```

And the fact that `||` is a short-circuit, which prevents NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: This is the cleanliest answer here. Might even use it myself since I have a similar case.

Comment: This seems to work. I added a null check for date too to avoid NPE.

Comment: @uraza I suspect a null date would be a bug so you could add `Objects.requireNonNull(date);` on the first line of your method.

Comment: This will fail for null start & end dates and gives opposite results,

Answer (score 3):

Java 8's enhances to the [`Comaparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface provide a pretty elegant way of doing this:

```
private static final Comparator<Date> NULL_SAFE_BEFORE =
        Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder());

private static final Comparator<Date> NULL_SAFE_AFTER =
        Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder());

public static boolean isWithinRange(Date date, Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    return NULL_SAFE_BEFORE.compare(startDate, date) < 0 &&
            NULL_SAFE_AFTER.compare(date, endDate) < 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some example code showing how to use this in the context of the Question?

Comment: @BasilBourque not sure what you mean - I did not change the signature of the `isWithinRange` method. Could you clarify what exactly you're asking?

Comment: Yes, I see that now. I misread you code, thinking you were quoting from the `Comparator` class rather than using it.

Answer (score 1):

This should be equivalent:

```
public static boolean isWithinRange(Date date, Date startDate, Date endDate) {
    return !(startDate != null && date.before(startDate) || endDate != null && date.after(endDate));
}
```